# Minimal harmonic functions on a poset

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, potential-theory

This just a question about concept and nomenclature; and I haven't been able to find an adequate answer in the literature so far.
Suppose $\Bbb{P}$ is locally finite poset with a unique
minimal element $\emptyset$. Recall that a real-valued
function $\varphi: \Bbb{P} \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is *harmonic* if

\begin{equation}
\varphi(x) = \sum_{x \lhd \, y} \varphi(y)
\end{equation}

where $x \lhd \, y$ indicates that $x$ is covered by $y$ with respect to the partial order.

**Question:** Is the following **the** correct definition of *minimal* harmonic function; as used, for example, in defining the *minimal* part of the Martin boundary of $\Bbb{P}$?

*Definition: A harmonic function $\varphi: \Bbb{P} \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is said to be **minimal** if it is non-negative (i.e. $\varphi(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb{P}$), normalised (in the sense that $\varphi(\emptyset) = 1$), and has the property that whenever we have a decomposition $\varphi = s\varphi_1 + (1-s)\varphi_2$ for some pair of non-negative, normalised harmonic functions $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ with $0 < s < 1$ **then** either $\varphi = \varphi_1 = \varphi_2$.*

thanks, Ines.